# Access ControlTemplate components (windows 8 app)

Tags: wpf, templates, controls

I would like to combine some UI elements into a Control, and then access them by code. However I can't figure it out.
The control template:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridViewStyle1" TargetType="GridView">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
                    <Grid>                      
                        <TextBox x:Name="theTextBox" Text="The Text" />                         
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

And a reference to the Template:

```
<GridView x:Name="myGridView1" Style="{StaticResource TileControl}"/>
```

So what I'm looking for is something like this for example:

```
myGridView1.Style.Template.Gridview.theTextBox.Text
```

But I can't find it. Any idea how I can do that? Or maybe I'm on the wrong track since it shouldn't be so complicated?

Comment: Why would you do that? I mean, ControlTemplates are not intended to be manipulated from code...

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve ControlTemplate-generated element you can use something like (after the template has been applied to the control)

```
yourcontrol.Template.FindName("ControlElementTemplateToFind")
```

See also [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613586.aspx)